# Using vim in scala sbt console, scala repl ?

Tags: vim, console, sbt, read-eval-print-loop

Is there way to edit and enter current command on a sbt console(scala repl) using VIM, like we do on bash. As bash gives you the option to able to edit your current command from vim.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no built-in support for editing the current command using Vim.

Both sbt 1.x and Scala 2.12.x use JLine2 for line editing (history using up arrow, and tab completion). While JLine2 has rudimentary vi command emulation, it does not seem to have the support to send current line to the `VISUAL` editor.

#### vi command emulation

To enable vi movements, set the following in `$HOME/.inputrc`:

```
set editing-mode vi
```

When you start Scala REPL, type `ESC` or `Ctrl + [`. Now you can:

- `k` to go to previous history.
- `?something` to search for "something" in history buffer, `n` to search again.
- `w` to move to next word, `b` to move to previous word.
- `i` to come back to insert mode.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, here’s some vim script I sometimes use to run the contents of the current vim buffer in the Scala REPL:

```
" Write the current buffer to a temp file and load it in the Scala REPL
function RunInScalaREPL()
    let l:tmpfile = tempname() . '.scala'
    execute 'write ' . l:tmpfile
    execute '!scala -i ' . l:tmpfile
endfunction
command Scala call RunInScalaREPL()
command REPL call RunInScalaREPL()
```